# Replacing values in csv using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to overwrite the email value in userinfo.csv with the email address from email.csv
userid and u_user values are matching and unique in both csv's. The email address value in userinfo.csv in not good and needs to be overwritten with the email value from email.csv.

How do I match userid in both csv's and append email value?

No idea where to even start. Any help, please.

```
email.csv
userid,email
1234,user4@email.com
1235,user5@email.com

userinfo.csv
u_work,u_user,u_address,u_city,u_state,u_zip,u_email,u_phonehome
1234,here,there,everywhere,55555,1234@bad.org,555-555-5555
away,1235,there,here,everywhere,66666,1235@bad.com,666-666-6666

new.csv
u_work,u_user,u_address,u_city,u_state,u_zip,u_email,u_phonehome
1234,here,there,everywhere,55555,user4@email.com,555-555-5555
away,1235,there,here,everywhere,66666,user5@email.com,666-666-6666
```

Comment: Please comment/confirm/update the `userinfo.csv` in your question according to @Bacon Bits comment: "*Your CSVs as presented are not valid*".

Comment: You could use the [`[Join-Object] cmdlet`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/): 
`Import-CSV .\userinfo.csv | LeftJoin (Import-CSV .\email.csv) userid {$Right.$_} | Export-CSV .\New.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSVs as presented are not valid.  The header row has 8 fields.  Row 1 has 7 fields.  That's not valid.  I'm assuming that it should look like this:

```
userinfo.csv
u_work,u_user,u_address,u_city,u_state,u_zip,u_email,u_phone
home,1234,here,there,everywhere,55555,1234@bad.org,555-555-5555
away,1235,there,here,everywhere,66666,1235@bad.com,666-666-6666
```

In other words, that `u_phonehome` is actually `u_phone` and `home` is on the wrong row in your examples.

Your basic steps are:

A. Import `email.csv` into a hash table for quick lookup.

```
$emails = @{}
Import-Csv email.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $email[$_.userid] = $_.email
}
```

B. Import `userinfo.csv`, and replace the email addresses where necessary.

```
$NewCSV = Import-Csv userinfo.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($emails.ContainsKey($_.u_user)) {
        $_.u_email = $emails[$_.u_user]
    }
    $_
}
```

C. Write the output file.

```
$NewCSV | Export-Csv new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also do step B with a `Select-Object` and a calculated property, but this is a bit easier to write.

Comment: Thanks for the basic steps. I must be missing something. I am getting an error:

Comment: Unable to index into an object of type System.String

Comment: @SteveGlover What are you running that creates an error?  Which command is throwing the error?  What's the complete error message?

Comment: Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\TestScripts\New Text Document2.ps1:3 char:5
+     $email[$_.Student_id] = $_.Student_email
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: @SteveGlover You've got a basic logic error then.  Either `$email` was not initialized as a hash table, or you've mixed the `$_` pipeline with the non-pipelined `foreach` statement (e.g., `foreach ($Student in $CSV) { $_.Student_id }` is invalid), or either `Student_id` or `Student_email` isn't the right spelling of the header in the CSV file.

Comment: Just the tip I needed. Figured it out, using your code from above.

Comment: array was foreach-object {$email[       needed to be changed to foreach-object {$emails[        Marking as completed. Thank you for not giving up on me and teaching me something new. Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I have copied the working script.                                                                                                                $emails = @{}
Import-Csv C:\app\files\edit\ademail.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $emails[$_."Description"] = $_."mail"
}


$NewCSV = Import-Csv C:\app\files\edit\bademails.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($emails.ContainsKey($_."Student_id")) {
        $_."Student_email" = $emails[$_."Student_id"]
    }
    $_
}


$NewCSV | Export-Csv c:\app\files\good\allgood.csv -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0):

You'd use Regex for the match and replace for the modification of specific stings. This is a common thing that is done, and there are many articles and posts on the topic. So, give the below resources a shot and come back with your effort if you need further assistance.

For example:

Windows PowerShell: Writing Regular Expressions

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx

Powershell: The many ways to use regex - Kevin Marquette

https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression

```
"Hello. Yes, this is a cat." -replace 'cat','dog'
"Hello. Yes, this is a dog." -replace [regex]::Escape('.'),'!'
("Hello. Yes, this is a dog.").Replace('.','!')
```

PSTip A difference between the –replace operator and String.Replace method

https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/12/pstip-a-difference-between-the-replace-operator-and-string-replace-method/

```
(Get-Content C:\test\test.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b",'<$0>'} | 
Set-Content C:\test\test.txt
```

[Powershell Regex find emails and replace email with (<email>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951624/powershell-regex-find-emails-and-replace-email-with-email)

```
$txt='<p class=FillText><a name="InternetMail_P3"></a>First.Last@company-name.com</p>'
$re="[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
[regex]::MAtch($txt, $re, "IgnoreCase ")
```

[Using Regex in Powershell to grab email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564679/using-regex-in-powershell-to-grab-email)

Comment: $CSV1 = Import-Csv "c:\testscripts\adstudents.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv "c:\testscripts\studentsnospaces.csv"
$CSV1 | ForEach-Object
{$StudentID = $_.Student_id, $Email = $_.Student_email}

Comment: $CSV2 | Where-Object { $_.StudentID -eq $StudentID } |
Select-Object School_id, Student_id, Student_number, State_id, Last_name, Middle_name, First_name, Grade, Gender, DOB, Race, Hispanic_Latino, Ell_status, Frl_status, IEP_status, Student_street, Student_city, Student_state, Student_zip, @{n='Student_email';e={ $Email }}, Contact_relationship, Contact_type, Contact_name, Contact_phone, Contact_email, Username, Password

Comment: Export-Csv "c:\testscripts\NewFile.csv"

Comment: Trying to match Student_id in both files (they are unique) and replace Student_email value in csv2 with Student_email value from csv1.